# Find Path to Sum - recursion

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

As one of the coding exercise I tried to print the path, which you will encounter to find a particular sum, in this case: 3.

The incrementing values would be 1 and 2.
Thus the shortest path to the sum would `return [1,2] or [2,1].`

But I can't try to put the path to an array - I have tried putting indexes through the params, but the array would be overwritten (no wonder). Could someone suggest how to tackle this problem?

```js
    const toSum = target => {

      const calc = sum => {
        if (sum == target) return 0;
        if (sum > target) return Infinity;

        const temp1 = 1 + calc(sum + 2);
        const temp2 = 1 + calc(sum + 1);

        return Math.min(temp1, temp2);
       };

      return calc(0);
    };

    console.log(toSum(3));
```

Comment: hi Tomas Eglinskas if you have questions about the logic?

Answer (score 0):

pass an array and fill it with the current added value

```js
const toSum = target => {
    const calc = (sum ,res) => {
      if (sum == 0) return res
      if (sum > 2) {
          res.push(2)
          return calc(sum-2,res)
      } 
      res.push(1)
      return calc(sum-1,res)
    };
    
  if (target <1  ) return "need to be above 1" 
  if (!Number.isInteger(target) ) return "need to be an integer"
    return calc(target,[])
  };

console.log(toSum(3));
```